# Retrieve PE-Image of a loaded DLL on Windows CE / Mobile

Tags: windows, dll, windows-ce, portable-executable, windows-mobile-6.5

I want to access the code of a loaded module in memory and assign it to an appropriate structur like IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.

This works fine on the Windows Desktop platform (tested only on Win 7 Prof SP 1) but it does not work for Win CE 6.0 and Win Mobile 6.5.3.

I did not have the opportunity to test on various ranges of different Windows OS versions, but i am assuming that the behaviour of e.g. Win CE 6.0
is representative for Win CE 5.0 and Win CE 7.0 too. At least in this simple case. Please correct me if i am wrong at this point.

I am using the Following code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

    HMODULE module;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER * image_dos_header;
    char * code;

    //
    // Retrieve the module handle, e.g. the address in memory where the dll was loaded
    //
    module = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));

    //
    // IMAGE_DOS_HEADER::e_magic containes the PE-Header magic 0x4d5a
    //
    image_dos_header = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)module;

    //
    // code points to "MZ"
    //
    code = (char *)module;

    return 0;
}
```

Now on Windows Desktop this works fine, whereas on the mobile platforms (Win CE, Win Mobile) it seems not to work, because the returned module handle points to memory that either contains only the value 0 (Win CE) or undefined values (Win ME).

I have read about the XIP technology and i firstly suspected the ROM to be the reason why it won't work on the mobile platforms. However the described error also occurs for a DLL compiled on my own and residing on the flash memory. So i think XIP cannot be the problem?

Does anybody has an advice on this topic?

Regards

Comment: The source code of CE kernel is available for people who get Platform Builder (was available also in the demo version up to CE6, IIRC). Looking into the code may help you understand what the HANDLE means inside CE and if you have a way to collect the information you need. I am pretty sure that for XIP modules the header and other info from the exe file are not kept inside the OS image, but for DLLs loaded from other media or added as files to the image that should be possible.

Comment: Windows ce 6 memory layout has been re-designed in contrast to Windows CE 5 based OS like Windows Mobile 6.5.x. The OS memory layout and functions are different to current desktop windows (and more or less based on something like Windows NT 3.5). Some useful information is at http://phrack.org/issues/63/6.html: see list.cpp and following.